# CSS3 animation not showing in IE 11 and IE Edge

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created a CSS background animation that works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE Edge and IE 11 only the background color animates. In Safari only the image in the upper left-hand corner animates. I'm not sure what the issue is. My code is below and my JS Fiddler example is https://jsfiddle.net/3vq7L9g2/

I updated my code but it's still not working

```
<div class="my-group">

</div>


 div {
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
    }


     .my-group {

        animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
                -webkit-animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .my-group:hover {

        animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
        -webkit-animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }



    @keyframes animatedBackgroundfrom {
    from {

       background:   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
       url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
       url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
       url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
       background-color: #fbaf5d;
    }

    to {

     background:
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
     background-color: #448ccb;
     }
    }


    @keyframes animatedBackgroundto {

    from {

     background:
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
     url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
     background-color: #448ccb;
    }

    to {

     background:
      url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
      url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
      url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
      url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
     background-color: #fbaf5d;
     }
    }

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackgroundfrom {
       from {

           background:
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
           background-color: #fbaf5d;
       }

       to {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
         }
       }


    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackgroundto {

       from {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
       }

       to {

         background:
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #fbaf5d;
         }
       }





      @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackgroundfrom {
       from {

           background:
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
           background-color: #fbaf5d;
       }

       to {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
         }
       }


    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackgroundto {

       from {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
       }

       to {

         background:
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #fbaf5d;
         }
       }






         @-o-keyframes animatedBackgroundfrom {
       from {

           background:
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
           url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
           background-color: #fbaf5d;
       }

       to {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
         }
       }


    @-o-keyframes animatedBackgroundto {

       from {

         background:
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
         url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #448ccb;
       }

       to {

         background:
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
          url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
         background-color: #fbaf5d;
         }
       }
```

Comment: Is the keyframe def inside a media-query, then there's a known bug?   https://caniuse.com/#search=Keyframe

Comment: background-image source is not an animatable property in IE-Edge

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I defined Background image, background position Background repeat in the div that animates instead of just calling the animation name this fixed the problem. Now my animation works in IE 11, IE Edge and Safari

```
 .my-group {

background-image:
    url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg),
    url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg),
    url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg),
    url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg);
    background-position: -6% -2%, 109% -2%, -6% 100%, 104% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    animation: coreanimatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: coreanimatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: coreanimatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackgroundfrom 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.my-group:hover {

    animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackgroundto 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

@keyframes animatedBackgroundfrom {
from {

   background:   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
   background-color: #fbaf5d;
}

to {

 background:
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
 background-color: #448ccb;
 }

}


@keyframes animatedBackgroundto {
from {

         background:
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -30% -1% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 0% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -30% 100% no-repeat,
 url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 130% 100% no-repeat;
 background-color: #448ccb;
}

to {

   background:   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/h/haines_nath_zootallur_101s.jpg) -6% -2% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/n/nufsaid~~~~_rise~~~~~_101s.jpg) 109% -2% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/g/gainsb_serg_lepacha20_101s.jpg) -6% 100% no-repeat,
   url(https://cdn2.dustygroove.com/images/products/r/rempis_dave_ithra~~~~_101s.jpg) 104% 100% no-repeat;
   background-color: #fbaf5d;
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

GSAP (green sock animation platform) is designed for such situations.

You can use Timelinelight to solve this problem using a bit of js code.
https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineLite